# Retrieving the attribute value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is the code I have written with angular js. using jquery I want to get the      "data-index" attribute value

```
<div class="claimed" droppable value="2">

        <div class="phase1" ng-repeat="item in Phase1claimed"
            data-index="{{$index}}" draggable value="2">
            <div class="ClaimedAccordion" accordion-title="{{item.name}}" unclaimhi="unclaimhi('1');">

                {{item.newLabel}} <br /> {{item.desc}} <br /> {{item.effort}} <br />
                {{item.owner}} <br /> {{item.issues}} <br /> {{item.comments}} <br />
                {{item.dependency}} <br /> {{item.content}}
            </div><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: a great place to start would be the api documentation -> http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) jQuery API function to get the data attribute

```
$('.phase1').attr('data-index');
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to get the data attributes `data-index` using the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/yLdPm/)**

```
$('.phase1').data('index');
```

You can use [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) to find out element with phase class within element with claimed class.

```
$('.claimed .phase1').data('index');
```

You can use attr to get the attribute but using the attr will not get you value being changed  by javascript. Its worth reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr) for difference between `data` and `attr`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/xSjN9/)**

```
<a id="foo" data-foo="bar" href="#">foo!</a>

alert( $('#foo').attr('data-foo') );
alert( $('#foo').data('foo') );
```

Comment: how can i get the index number of corresponding data like i have three data-foo as bar for different element and i want to get the index of the element using their data attribute..

Comment: As for as my understanding you want to get the element by attributes,  $('[data-foo]').each(function(){ alert(this.tagName); }); you can use eq to get particular element alert($('[data-foo]').eq(0).attr("id"));